# User.findOne is not a function for knexjs (postgresql)

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to use passport but i get this error in my code

```
TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
```

I followed docs in passport.js , and this my code

```
const HeaderAPIKeyStrategy = require('passport-headerapikey').HeaderAPIKeyStrategy

const knexDb = knex({ client: 'pg', connection: {
    host : process.env.HOST,
    user : process.env.USER,
    password : process.env.PASSWORD,
    database : process.env.DATABASE,
    port: process.env.PORT
  }});

const bookshelf = require('bookshelf');
const securePassword = require('bookshelf-secure-password');
const db = bookshelf(knexDb);
db.plugin(securePassword);

const User = db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  hasSecurePassword: true
});


passport.use(new HeaderAPIKeyStrategy(
  { header: 'Authorization', prefix: 'Api-Key ' },
  false,
  function(apikey, done) {
    console.log(apikey)    
    User.findOne({ apikey: apikey }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.post('/api/authenticate', 
  passport.authenticate('headerapikey', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Authenticated" })
  });
```

I've read about knexjs and postgresql and i think there is a different sequelizerjs use for psql but passportjs docs only for mongoos , so can someone help me to understand the problem here in my code and what i'm missing and if there is a good docs to use sequelize for psql for this purpose of code using kenxjs

After looking around for some helpful info , I updated my code to this : but i still don't know how it works so can someone put me on the right pass :

```
passport.use(new HeaderAPIKeyStrategy(
  { header: 'Authorization', prefix: 'Api-Key ' },
  false,
  function(apikey, done) {
    console.log(apikey)
    User.forge().where({ apikey: apikey }).fetch().then((user) => {
      // console.log('err', err)
      console.log('user', user)
      done(null, user);
    });
    // User.findOne({ apikey: apikey }, function (err, user) {
    //   console.log('err', err)
    //   console.log('user', user)
    //   if (err) { return done(err); }
    //   if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
    //   return done(null, user);
    // });
  }
));
```

but now when i `res.json(req.body)`, i get this response

```
{
    "token": "jfaskdl"
}
```

Comment: Although bookshelf.js uses knex.js you're better off tagging such questions with bookshelf.js. Also avoid tagging with unrelated tags.

Comment: As you can see in [Bookshelf's API documentation](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#section-Model) Models have no `findOne` method, so this is probably an issue with Passport's docs or your code. Also, you mention "Sequelize" in your question, but your examples show Bookshelf.

Comment: @devius findOne as mentioned is for mongoos, so what'm looking for is how to use it or something similar like forge() with kenx psql

Answer (score 0):

Here the error message that the user gets when executing `findOne()` method with **knex.js/bookshelf.js** is simply because **it is a Moongoose method to find (one) element in a MongoDB database, not a knex/bookshelf method.**

FYI : The equivalent in knex would be

```
knex.select('token_column_value')
    .from('user_table')
    .where({ apikey: 'apikey' });
```

Or any examples mentionned in their docs where the select syntax is explained :

https://knexjs.org/#Builder-select